# Failed to provision a cloud shell, Azure error

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

I just subscribed to Azure with my Github student, then I start to learn its feature with no error in cloud shell, then I try in the other day my cloud shell pop up this error message:

```
Requesting a Cloud Shell.Failed to provision a Cloud Shell: 
{
    "code":"TenantDisabled",
    "message":"Cloud Shell has been disabled in directory ...
}
```

Comment: Are you still blocked here? Is this happening with both [Bash](https://shell.azure.com/bash) and [PowerShell](https://shell.azure.com/powershell) environments?

Comment: I also faced the same issue in one of my subscriptions. For me, the behavior was interim. It got resolved itself after few hours.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like a common error unless Cloud Shell has been specifically [disabled in your environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cloud-shell/troubleshooting#disabling-cloud-shell-in-a-locked-down-network-environment). If you see this happening consistently, try removing all your [Cloud Shell resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cloud-shell/persisting-shell-storage), i.e., the associated Resource group, Storage account and File share and re-configure it again.